# parse-server updating an existing user field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

**What I am trying to do**: I am using parse server with javaScript SDK to change a field  value for an already existing user.

**The code that i am using**

```
 var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        query.equalTo("username", "someUserName");

          query.find({
              success: function(users){
                  console.log("user found", users);
                   users.set("name", "new name");
                   users.save(null,{
                    success: function(updated){
                   //worked
                  },
                  error: function(error, updated){
                    //didn't work
                   }
                 });

       },
      error: function(error, users){
            console.error("error at querying: ", error);
       }
   });
```

**The issue** : this does not update the name field value.

**What i have discovered from researching this issue**
: seems like i have to utilize the sessioToken or/and masterKey like this(show below) but that also did not work.

```
  users.save(null,{useMasterKey:true}{
            success: function(updated){
               //worked
               }
```

I am quite confused at the moment, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your master key or session token should be the first parameter.Have a look at the Parse.Object.save API

https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html

Try something like this

```
users.save({useMasterKey:true}, {
        success: function(updated){
           //worked
        }
        error: function(err){
        }
});
```